# weight value has no effect

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm trying to put different weights on some places but no matter how much value I set, it always appears like it's on 100% influence. is this a bug? is there a way for me to fix this?
[image: weight painting ss]
the bones have already moved here, as you can see the ears are clipping through the head, which is why I need the different weights but it has no effect.
I'm using blender 2.79

Comment: Hello could you please share your file so that we understand better?

Comment: @moonboots hi, not sure how to put a file here but here's the file in Gdrive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FVHAbOoiY-NQwjziT5bbyCk-g82BbEyb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok I was not sure about my first answer but I think that it answers after all

Answer (score 1):

If these vertices are not part of any other vertex group, and even if the weight of your current vertex group is only 0.1, the influence of your bone on these vertices will be 100%. The vertices need to be part of at least one other vertex group if you want the influence to be shared. If a vertex is part of 2 vertex groups, with a weight of 1 in one vertex group, and a weight of 0.1 in a second, the influence of the first vertex group will be 10 times higher.